# Simultaneously post in both WordPress.com and self hosted WordPress blog

Tags: plugins, wordpress.com-hosting

I have a friend that wants to move her WordPress.com blog to self hosted. That part is done, except she would like to keep the WordPress.com blog going along the new self hosted.

Is there a way to post simultaneously to both? I thought of making a plugin to post to Wordpress.com when she publishes on her self hosted blog. Is that possible?

Ideally, she would post in her self hosted, and it would automatically post to WordPress.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She could install a plugin like [DJ Email Publish](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dj-email-publish/) on her self-hosted blog.  This will republish any post she creates to any blog that accepts e-mail posts.  This will allow her to write a post using any method she chooses on the self-hosted blog, and it will reappear on her WordPress.com blog.

Comment: That plugin looks promising. I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: I will have to customize the plugin, but it will do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If she has [Post by email](http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-by-email/) enabled, she can submit her post using the email addresses for each of the blogs at the same time.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I think she will want to use the editor to insert images, categories, tags, etc. I know she can do all that by email, but wouldn't be as user friendly. Thanks

Comment: @coopersita I just came across another plugin from Automattic called [syndication](https://github.com/Automattic/syndication) that will let you post to multiple blogs at once, rather than relying on email.

Answer (score 0):

She could install a plugin on her self-hosted blog that will create posts based on an RSS feed.  Doing this, she could post once to her WordPress.com blog, and the self-hosted blog would pick it up on RSS and republish.  One such plugin that will do this is [WP-o-Matic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-o-matic/).  Unfortunately, you won't be able to install this on your WordPress.com blog, so you wouldn't be able to go the other way.