# Not showing up on Wordpress Reader

Tags: blog

I'm hosting a WordPress site on Name.com (using Jetpack).  Although I can access my blog stats, etc. from wordpress.com, my posts aren't showing up on wordpress.com's reader or under topics.  I haven't broken any WordPress rules (excessive tags, crappy content, etc.).

Any idea how to get my posts to show up on the reader?

Comment: WordPress.com's reader only works with blogs hosted on WordPress.com, as far as I know.

Comment: I have <myblog>.wordpress.com as well as <myblog>.com, but I'm only posting on the second one.  If I were to redirect the wordpress.com blog, would that work? I don't want to pay $13 for site redirect unless that'll do it.  Thanks!

Comment: No, I doubt that would do it.

Comment: See [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/108072/32110) for ideas on how to cross-post blog entries from a self-hosted blog to a WordPress.com blog.